# How to Submit Post Via cURL & PHP

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, forms, automation

Thanks for reading.

I'm trying to submit a post via PHP. I'm filling in a large number of posts from a good amount of data I've scraped so I need this to be automated. I don't have the time (or desire) to manually input 700+ posts.

I am versatile with programming, but newer to WordPress (I've been saying that for almost a year but I still feel like it's true).

My cURL function is working great, I receive no errors and data back from curl_getinfo that is indicating it's working.

I dug into the Chrome Developer tools and did two things:
I looked at the form before it's sent and saw the action of the form:

```
http://domain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php
```

And then I submitted a test form to see which *$_REQUEST* variables were going through and I filled them in respectively.

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php';
//$url = 'http://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
$fields = array(
    "action" => "add-tag",
    "screen" => "edit-property_city",
    "taxonomy" => "property_city",
    "post_type" => "estate_property",
    "_wpnonce_add-tag" => "483c44d6e2",
    "_wp_http_referer" => "/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=property_city&post_type=estate_property",
    "tag-name" => $city,
    "slug" => $slug,
    "parent" => "-1",
    "description" => "description",
    "term_meta[pagetax]" => "page_id",
    "term_meta[category_featured_image]" => "",
    "term_meta[category_attach_id]" => "",
    "term_meta[category_tagline]" => "tag",
    "term_meta[category_tax]" => "property_city"
```

You'll notice I havea  second url/action. That's because when the form completes, the url in the chrome dev tools is admin-ajax.php. I figured that theres a redirect that I'm missing. I used my debugger in the backend to debug the action when I went throug the form but I got no where. The reason I don't use WordPress more often is because it's a nightmare on the backend with all the hooks and function slugs.

If anyone has any suggestions as to what I can do to automate custom posts, or if WordPress has a recommended way to automate posts, I'd genuinely appreciate any information. :)

I have also read about nonces and I'm under the impression they last for 24 hrs. I've checked a few times and they are valid.

## EDIT

Thanks to the responses on my post. Although it didn't help me successful post a Post via cURL, the WP-API was very helpful. I went into my database and looked at the content of my *wp_posts* and the foreign key relations to its *wp_postmeta* records. And from there realized what was needed to insert a succesful post.

Comment: Have you considered the REST API?

Comment: I haven't but I will. I unfortunately don't know much about the wordpress framework/CMS. So I'm not exactly sure what to search for. I'll read into it, thanks for reaching out, it's a big help. Any further recommendations are always welcome

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) and [wp-api](http://v2.wp-api.org/) they could help you automate your process without you needing to know too much about wordpress.